# How to I add more events to an existing instance of Full Calendar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, fullcalendar

I am looking at [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) but I ran into a couple problems.

Problem 1.

I don't know how to add new events to an existing instance

```
$('#calendar').fullCalender({ // options set }); // initial set.
```

So now say if I want to add a json feed to this later on and remove an existing feed. The only way I know how to do this is

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', "Calendar/GetDates");
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', "Calendar/GetDatesSearch?term=8");
```

I think this is kinda stupid as I got to select the calendar X times for each option? I tried to do

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalender(
    {
        addEventSource: "Calendar/GetDatesSearch?term=8",
        removeEventSource, "Calendar/GetDates"
    });
```

but this seems to like to generate a whole new calendar. So I will have multiple calendars(something I don't want).

My second problem is

I have a click event on a anchor tag

```
<a href="#" id="ReRender">Re-Render</a>
```

and then

```
$('#ReRender').click(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', "Calendar/GetDates");
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', "Calendar/GetDatesSearch?term=8");          
    return false;
});
```

The 1st I click on the anchor tag(ReRender) it works just fine. I click it a couple more times and hit the arrow to go to the next month it will render the same feed multiple times.

So I am guessing that everytime I do I click even it adds another feed even if it is the exact same feed.

So I click "ReRender" 50 times and hit next month. It thinks I have 50 feeds even though they are all the same feed.

Any recommendations on how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love fullCalendar!  Adding a new event is done like this...

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventObj, true);
```

The third parameter specifies if you want the event to stick if the feed is reRendered.  Usually I do.

Also to rerender your events...

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

Comment: All of this is documented under the 'Event Rendering' section in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry. I should have specified the reason I am not using rerenderEvents is because I need a new data feed. I like fullCalendar too but I would like it more if I would not have to do a selector for each option I want to add/change after it is created. It would be nice to do this all at once.

Comment: For a large number of operations you could easily do this:             var fullCal = $("#calendar");  then do your operations on fullCal.fullCalendar(....);

Comment: He is right, you shouldn't have to re-select for each method call.  Any plugin that follows conventions correctly should be returning the jquery object.  This way you could also chain your methods if you want.